# Why the global k scale determined by estimate_global_k_neighbor_scale() is 6?

Tags: cgal

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::FT FT;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point_3;
//populate points. The code is skipped for brevity.  
std::size_t k_scale = CGAL::estimate_global_k_neighbor_scale(points);
```

My input point are shown below.

```
0 0 0
1 0 0
2 0 0
3 0 0
4 0 0
5 0 0
6 0 0
7 0 0
8 0 0
9 0 0
```

The value of k scale is 6.  My understanding is that k_scale is simply the number of  neighbors necessary to  represent the curve/surface. Since this is a straight line, I was expecting 1 or 2(if including the current points). I thought it might be finding a surface because the input are 3d points. So, I called the method for 2d points, still the result is 6.

Comment: The code contains `if (nb < 6.) // do not consider values under 6`. Doesn't say why though.

Comment: @sloriot Is there a paper or some other reference to explain the concept and this limitation(don't consider value under 6)?